# SSL+IRM is it supported for SharePoint 2010+Windows 7

Tags: office-integration

The problem we have faced is the following

**Server side**

- SharePont 2010 Server
- SSL enabled and certificate request required
- IRM for the document library is enabled
- Custom content type inhereted from the standard Document CT with several fields of standard types

**Client side**

- Windows 7 x64
- MS Office 2010

**The problem**

When we create a new document (of the custom CT) in the document library (via Create New button on ribbon) and fill custom properties in MS Word 2010 (in document properties panel) ***then no custom properties get saved back to the SharePoint library*** (although the file itself and standard Document CT properies do get saved).

We are aware of the two possible client configurations that support SP and Office integration:

- Web Client service
- Web folders

But in either way we have the same result (described above)

However if we remove IRM support on the document library everything works fine

Please advise how we could overcome this behavior

**Summarizing all of this**

- HTTP+IRM = OK
- HTTPS wihout IRM = OK
- HTTPS+IRM = doesn't work (custom CT properties are ignored by MS Word)

What we are going to try is to utilize reverse proxy (TMG) to provide SSL encryption and leave SP farm with just HTTP and IRM enabled

Could it help?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. You should contact Microsoft Support and open a case. SharePoint is removing the IRM part on the server and stores the document unencrypted in the database. I think in the process of removing the protection they lose your content.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce and it does not require SSL.  Farm is 14.0.6126.5000.

Comment: This looks like a fairly similar issue with no fix, but does have a workaround. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981688.  I also noticed that when saving the file locally, then uploading it would prompt for the Properties in the custom CT that I could then fill out.  If I filled out the properties there, the Library displayed the properties and the properties came back down with the Document when opened from the Library.

Comment: If you upload from the web site the metadata is not transported trough the document. It is directly stored into the list item. So it won't be lost.

Comment: The metadata is lost unless you leverage the Upload control and manually input the metadata there.  If you simply click New, which opens the Word template, fill in the properties within the document, then save directly back to the List, the metadata does not appear.  The metadata is also missing when bringing that document back down into Word.

I've also validated this on Win 8 + Office 2013 x86 + SharePoint 2010 with Server 2012 RMS.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, this is by design.  Property promotion will not function with RMS.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does provide an answer.  What the author is seeing is "by design".  There is no workaround, no fix, and so forth.

Comment: if you will start your sentence by "Just FYI" it sounds like a comment and also you need to provide reference to what you are saying. :)

Comment: I don't have a public reference to provide to the author, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, Trevor. Property promotion does not work with RMS in case of creating a new document from MS Word BUT it does work in case of editing existing document in MS Word. Could you explain why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

Parallel Branch provide you online Microsoft SharePoint 2010 for Developers Course.This will help you to get more information about how to add Web Part to Share Point page,share point work flows,Business Intelligence.